# How to merge(columns) outputs of two SELECT statements in oracle sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have two Select queries.

The first Select query gives the output which has two columns viz.

```
A   B
------
1   2    
3   4    
5   6    
7   8
```

The second Select query given the output which as two columns viz Column B and Column C. All the values in Column B of this select statement matches the values of Column B of the first Select statement.i.e

```
B   C
------
2   25    
4   50    
6   30    
8   50
```

Now, I need to merge the outputs of the above two Select queries. i.e

```
A   B   C
----------
1   2   25    
3   4   50    
5   6   30    
7   8   50
```

I cannot use views to store the output of the two select queries. I need to use the Column B in both select queries to merge. However, I am not able to figure out how to go about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have *elaborated* queries (not just *tables* to join), you may try using `with` construction

```
  with 
    Query1 as ( -- <- Put your 1st Query text here 
      select A,
             B
       ...
    ),
    Query2 as ( -- <- Put your 2nd Query text here 
      select B,
             C
       ...
    )  

 select Query1.A,
        Query1.B,
        Query2.C
   from Query1, 
        Query2
  where Query1.B = Query2.B
```

If your case is not *that complicated*, e.g. both Query1 and Query2 are in fact *tables*, say `Table1` and `Table2` you can do well with a simpler solution:

```
 select Table1.A,
        Table1.B,
        Table2.C 
   from Table1,
        Table2
  where Table1.B = table2.B
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you tables like having fields like

```
TableA(A ,B) , TableB(B,C)
```

Try using `JOIN` like

```
SELECT TableA.A , TableA.B, TableB.C
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableA.B = TableB.B;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by joining your first table to your second table using an `INNER JOIN` on the `B` column:

```
SELECT  T1.A,
        T1.B,
        T2.C
  FROM  Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.B = T1.B
```

Note that I called your first table `Table1` (alias `T1`) and your second table `Table2` (alias `T2`) as I was unsure of their names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT one.a, one.b, two.c
 FROM table1 one JOIN table2 two
 ON one.b = two.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join

```
SELECT A.A,
   A.B,
   B.C
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON B.B = A.B
```